# C# collection initializer – is it possible to add an element optionally, based on a condition?

Tags: c#

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var ids = projectId.HasValue ? new List<Guid> { projectId.Value } : new List<Guid>();
```

Is there a more succinct way of creating a list in one line of code, with one element added **optionally**?

Comment: Maybe you would consider wrapping List<T> and overloading Add(T) method with condition inside.

Comment: In a single statement that is probably the best you can do. If you do this a lot you could add an extension method for creating collections from nullables.

Comment: @Lee an extension method doesn't sound like a bad idea, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't a good idea, but [in C# 6, collection initializers also work when `Add()` is an extension method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).

This means you can write the extension `Add()` like this:

```
public static void Add<T>(this List<T> list, T? item) where T : struct
{
    if (item.HasValue)
    {
        list.Add(item.Value);
    }
}
```

And then this code will do what you want:

```
var list = new List<Guid> { projectId };
```

Note that this will only work for value types (because of the `T`/`T?` distinction) and there is no simple way to make it work for reference types.

Also, I would find the line above very surprising, being more succinct is not always better. Which is why I actually wouldn't use this code.

Comment: Thank you! And now that I have thought about it, you are right in that shorter is not always better.

Comment: If someone who wrote that worked in my company, I would beat them to death with their own stapler.

Comment: @JoeEnos Saying that it's not a good twice is not good enough for you? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this using a extension method like this:

```
public static void AddIfNotNull<T>(this List<T> list, T? value) where T : struct
{
    if(value != null)
    {
        list.Add(value.Value);
    }
}
```

Than it could be used like this:

```
var ids = new List<Guid>();
ids.AddIfNotNull(projectId);
```

Maybe not as "crafty" (and not a one-liner) as your proposal, but in my opinion it is much easier to read and understand. If desired to be used as a one-liner you could modify the return type of the extension to be the list. That would make it possible to be used something like `var ids = new List<Guid>().AddIfNotNull(projectId);`

Comment: This won't compile since `T` is `Guid` but `projectId` is `Guid?`. If you're going to make an extension method you might as well implement the desired behaviour i.e. a function `T? -> List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea for an extension method (the name could definitely be improved, maybe `PossiblyCreateSingletonList`?):

```
public static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static List<T> SingletonList<T>(this Nullable<T> item) where T : struct
    {
        return item.HasValue ? new List<T> { item.Value } : new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Guid? projectId = null;

List<Guid> projectIds = projectId.SingletonList(); // empty list
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty succinct, but another option would be to use LINQ:

```
var ids = new[] { projectId }.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: That is almost of the same length and it hides the intention of the code.

Comment: You saved maybe 2 characters, but if I am reading this code in a project, I would think there is some complex querying going on. I wouldn't understand the original intention.

Comment: @YacoubMassad If the original question is truly the use case, then yep, I probably wouldn't do this. But the LINQ solution is a little more generic, allowing you to filter zero or more nullable values into only the non-null ones, in case you find yourself in a situation where you may not want to do exactly one. All depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the extension method route, it would have to look something like:

```
public static void AddIfNotNull<T>(this List<T> list, T? value)
    where T : struct
{
    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        list.Add(value.Value);
    }
}
```

You'd have to build a second extension method for reference types (`where T : class`) if you needed.